# Integrating Mailchimp opt in field with api to wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, integration, mailchimp, contact-form-7

Hy everyone.

I have followed to this tutorial instructiones http://www.limecanvas.com/a-mailchimp-opt-in-field-for-contact-form-7 but anyway subscribers didn't added to Mailchimp list.I have uploaded the api class php file, put the code in my functions.php
Anyway subscribers didn't appear in the Mailchimp list.Please help me with suggestiones.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put generally the name and email input without a number that was in tutorial just like this way `[text* your-name]` and `[email* your-email]` and all works fine!